# Activity result with flags FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have two Activities: `ActivityA and ActivityB`.

I start `ActivityB` with `startActivityForResult`:

```
Intent lIntent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
startActivityForResult(lIntent, 1);
```

I have this code to go back from `ActivityB` to `ActivityA`(ActivityB can call itselfs many time):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityB.this,ActivityA.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("files",
mChecked.toArray(new String[mChecked.size()]));
startActivity(intent);
//setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
```

That code runs fine without `setResult`. My problem is I have to set `RESULT_OK` to deal correctly with the result in `ActivityA`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1){
       if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){ <-- always 0 and not -1
         System.out.println("OK");
   }
    }
}
```

if I comment in `setResult` in ActivityB, onActivityResult is never called.
If I use `startActivity`, `onActivityResult` is called but the `resultCode` is not set.
How can I set the result code in my case?

**UPDATE**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FileChooserActivity.this,FtpContentListView.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("files", mChecked.toArray(new String[mChecked.size()]));
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
startActivity(intent);
```

with that code `onActivityResult` is called but the `resultCode` is 0 and not -1(RESULT_OK).

Thanks a lot for your help

Stefan

Comment: Not sure you can use onActivityResult without A calling B. As B calls itself many times, i would try to had an onActivityResult in B to finish every Activity before it is sent to A

Comment: why you want onActivityReasult If your going to CLEAR the top & start the Activity-A. Finish `B` after calling setResult. You will get `RESULT_OK` = -1.

Comment: when you use the flag clear top this will clear all data fetched by the last actvity(s), because this will destroy the recent activity(s).

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're after is to first start Activity B for result (as you are currently), then subsequently starting new instances of Activity B using the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT`. Note however, that you would need to finish previous instances of Activity B whenever you create new ones (as described in this gist https://gist.github.com/mcelotti/cc1fc8b8bc1224c2f145).

Alternatively, you could simply start all instances of Activity B for result and pass down the result until Activity A was reached:

```
@Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    setResult(resultCode);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a change in Activity-B :

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putStringArray("files",
mChecked.toArray(new String[mChecked.size()]));
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityB.this,ActivityA.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtras(b);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

Hope this works.